# Javascript Month Translation Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to use javascript to verify date formats for various countries. They all of course have a different way to formatting their dates.

What I want to do (but do not know how to do) is create an array of month objects.
Each month object would contain a number (1 for January 2 for February etc) and an array of strings for the months translations (may for example `{'May' 'Maj' ,Mai'}` This way I would have 12 objects one for each month. Can anyone show me how to make this array of objects.

I have tried

```
    var monthObj = new Object(),
    abrMon,
    number;

var months[11] = new monthObj[11];
months[0].num = 1;
months[0].abrMon = { 'Jan', 'Other' };
```

but I can not see why this is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is so much wrong with your code. First you usually don't define length for arrays:

```
var months[11] = new ...;
```

I say usually since you can create array with predefined length:

```
var months = new Array(12); // Please do *not* use
```

Should be written as

```
var months = []; // array
```

`new Object()` is not really used anymore, instead use:

```
var a = {} // object
```

Arrays are written as `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` not `{ 1, 2, 3 }`

You can tie this together to:

```
var months = []; // array
months[0] = {}; // object
months[0].num = 1;
months[0].abrMon = ['Jan', 'Other'];
```

And it seems like you will be fine with a two dimensional array:

```
var months = [
    ['Jan', 'Jen', 'Janu'],
    ['Feb', 'Fbr', 'Fyb'],
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can derive the month number from position; you don't need to store it.  Javascript uses 0=January, 1=February, etc.  So if you need to display a month number for humans, just add 1 to the Javascript number.

For the names, you can just use an array indexed by the month number:

```
var abrMonthNames = [
   ['Jan', 'jan', 'janv'],
   ...
   ['May', 'maj', 'mai'],
   ...
   ['Dec', 'dec', 'déc' ]
];
```

Then just look for the name in `abrMonthNames[monthIndex]` or grab it from `abrMonthNames[monthIndex][languageIndex]`.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in `var months[11] = new monthObj[11];`  I think you want to be doing `months[11] = new Object();`

Also, your `{ 'Jan', 'Other' }` is an invalid object - objects are always key value pairs.  Change it to `[ 'Jan', 'Other']` to get that kind of structure.

Comment: Wups, my bad.  Fixed now.  It's still really wacky.

Comment: From OP's code it doesn't seem that `months` are ever defined and `months[11]` will throw a ReferenceError

Comment: OP was under the impression that `var months[11]` was the way to *declare* an array of size 11 (which is also an error, since it needs to be size 12, to hold objects at indices 0 through 11).